# My 3D printer shows inbuilt designs, but my designs are invisible

Tags: ultimaker-cura, 3d-models, 3d-design, tronxy-x5, mattercontrol

My designs are invisible on 3D printer LCD screen, i.e. the name of my design is showing up, but the part is missing and if I slice it with the software given by the 3D-printer company it works, but if I use any other slicer like Cura or Matter Control, it's not working.

I'm unable to add images as I'm new here.

I have a Tronxy X5SA 3D printer with a touch display.

I contacted the company, but they can't understand my issue, that's why seeking your help.

Comment: You should be able to add images now, as your reputation is greater than 10. It would be interesting to see the issue that you are describing, and may help others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the "Chitu code" plugin from the Cura website, some companies use the Chitu board as their printer's CPU and Tronxy does that. Without the plugin, it won't show a preview of your design and also it won't print.